# EventEmitter Memory Leaked

Tags: node.js, azure, meteor, storage, blob

Am using meteor. I build a meteor package which helps in uploading files to blob storage . Am getting the following error. This error occurs only once in 5 times.

```
W20141025-15:22:40.195(5.5)? (STDERR) (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
W20141025-15:22:40.546(5.5)? (STDERR) Trace
W20141025-15:22:40.546(5.5)? (STDERR)     at addListener (events.js:160:15)
W20141025-15:22:40.546(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/user/boutfeeds/packages/jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/.build.jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/npm/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:399:31
W20141025-15:22:40.547(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/user/boutfeeds/packages/jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/.build.jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/npm/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:516:5
W20141025-15:22:40.547(5.5)? (STDERR)     at SharedKey.signRequest (/Users/user/boutfeeds/packages/jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/.build.jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/npm/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/signing/sharedkey.js:81:3)
W20141025-15:22:40.547(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.StorageServiceClient._buildRequestOptions (/Users/user/boutfeeds/packages/jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/.build.jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/npm/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:498:27)
W20141025-15:22:40.634(5.5)? (STDERR)     at operation (/Users/user/boutfeeds/packages/jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/.build.jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/npm/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:255:10)
W20141025-15:22:40.634(5.5)? (STDERR)     at func [as _onTimeout] (/Users/user/boutfeeds/packages/jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/.build.jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload/npm/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:422:11)
W20141025-15:22:40.635(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

The code is here

```
 azureUpload:function(fileName,accountName,key,container,callback) {

      var buffer = new Buffer(this.data);
      retryOperations = new azure.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter();
      blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, key).withFilter(retryOperations);
      var blockId = this.blockArray[this.blockArray.length-1];
      var stream = new ReadableStreamBuffer(buffer);
      var self = this;
      Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
      var myFuture = new Future;


      blobService.createBlockFromStream(blockId,container,fileName,stream,stream.size(),function(err,response)
            {

                if(err)
                {
                    myFuture.return();
                }
                else if (response)
                {     


                 if (self.bytesUploaded+self.data.length >= self.size)
                    {
                         blobService.commitBlocks(container, fileName, {LatestBlocks: self.blockArray}, function(error, result){
                                if(error){
                                 myFuture.return();

                                } else {
                                    myFuture.return({url:"https://"+accountName+".blob.core.windows.net/"+container+"/"+fileName});
                                }
                            });



                    }
                    else
                    {
                         myFuture.return();
                    }


                }

            });

        return myFuture.wait();



      }
```

You can view the full source code here https://github.com/jamesfebin/azure-blob-upload/blob/master/azureupload.js (Scroll down to azureUpload function)

Answer (score 1):

Node has default of 10 event emitters. This can be over loaded easily by giving 15 concurrent request to http server... This can be stopped by setting process.setMaxListeners(0). So it won't show that errors.. Refer more here http://nodejs.org/api/events.html